# Keep Case Names in Regresson Object when plotting from a Tibble

Tags: r, regression, tibble

From the setNames help in R:

```
x <- 1:20
y <-  setNames(x + (x/4 - 2)^3 + rnorm(20, sd = 3),
           paste("O", x, sep = "."))
ww <- rep(1, 20); ww[13] <- 0
summary(lmxy <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2)+I(x^3) + I((x-10)^2), weights = ww),
    cor = TRUE)
variable.names(lmxy)
variable.names(lmxy, full = TRUE)  # includes the last
case.names(lmxy)
case.names(lmxy, full = TRUE)      # includes the 0-weight case
```

If I plot the regression object using:

```
plot(lmxy, 1)
```

I can see the case names in the plot. **This is what I want**.

However, if the data is stored as a tibble:

```
tt = as.tibble(cbind(x, y, ww))

lmxy_tt = lm(y ~ x + I(x^2)+I(x^3) + I((x-10)^2), weights = ww, data = tt)

plot(lmxy_tt, 1)
```

The case names are lost.

My data is usually stored in tibbles but I want a way to maintain the case names in the plot. I know tibbles doesn't support row names.

I've tried:

```
plot(lm(setNames(y1, paste("O", x1, sep = ".")) ~ x1 + I(x1^2)+I(x1^3) + I((x1-10)^2), weights = ww1, data = tt), 1)
```

To make things clearer, this is a toy example using the mtcars dataset of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
library(tidyverse)
cars = mtcars
cars$name = row.names(cars)
cars = as.tibble(cars)

cars = cars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~ lm(set_names(wt, name) ~ hp, data = .x)))
```

Now if I plot the result:

```
 plot(cars$model[[1]], 1)
```

I can see the case names as '1' and '5' but I want the car models labeled.
"Mazda RX4" etc. I want to somehow have the case names saved into the regression model instead of the defaults of '1', '2' etc. using 'setNames', 'set_names' or another method.

Hope this is clearer.

Thanks

Comment: When you create the dataset, the names of the vector are lost.  You can check the `str`.

Comment: That's right. But even if I save the names in another column:
tt = as.tibble(cbind(x, y, ww, names = names(y)))

plot(lm(setNames(y, names) ~ x + I(x1^2)+I(x1^3) + I((x1-10)^2), weights = ww, data = tt), 1)

will still not keep the case names